# Why is this code causing multiple threads to wait on a lock that isn't held

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3, locking, fork-join

I have a multi threaded program that operates on a directory like structure (AWS S3) to update items in the directories.

The structure is fixed. At the top level I have of directories, and under each directory I have only file items. I have a base thread that spawns tasks for the items under each directory to update each item in pararel. I have a fork join implementation with a monitor to manage the parallelism.

I call this function for every directory and it spawns substasks for the items under each directory. Unfortunately almost all my threads wait, and are never awoken. Though, there is one thread that runs normally, and is updating items, but that is very slow. I don't know why I have threads that are waiting and are never awoken.

```
void compute() {
try {
  if (isFileItem()) {
    updateItem();
    synchronized (isBaseThreadFinished) {
      while (!isBaseThreadFinished.get()) {
        isBaseThreadFinished.wait();
      }
    }
    if (atomicInt.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
      markDirectoryAsCompleted()
    }
  } else {
    ObjectListing listings = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, key);
    processListings(listings.getObjectSummaries());
    while (listings.isTruncated()) {
      listings = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listings);
      processListings(listings.getObjectSummaries());
      atomicInt.incrementBy(listings.length())
    }
    synchronized (isBaseThreadFinished) {
      isBaseThreadFinished.set(true);
      isBaseThreadFinished.notifyAll();
    }
  }
} catch {...}
```

I don't understand how a thread could wait forever with this code because the directory thread (the one which spawns the sub-tasks) will start first, and eventually finish and release all waiting threads.

Comment: You show only one function in your example. How many threads can enter it at the same time?

Comment: Are you aware that `isBaseThreadFinished.notifyAll()` does not do _anything_ unless some other thread already is in a call to `isBaseThreadFinished.wait()`?

Comment: With that little code it's really hard to tell, but here are some guesses: 1) you might synchronize on the same monitor (e.g. `isBaseThreadFinished`) and thus all threads wait for that monitor to be released 2) the threads aren't locked in Java code but by the filesystem, i.e. while one thread accesses a directory another can't

Comment: A thread dump will tell you exactly what lock each thread is waiting for and which thread has each lock. Update your question with a thread dump and we can help you decipher it.

Comment: @Thomas if N threads all attempt to synchronize on the same object, then one of them _must_ succeed. You could get a deadlock if the one that succeeds then waits for one of the others to do something before it will release the lock, but that seems unlikely in this case. The code snippet shows nothing of interest happening inside `synchronized` blocks. (Assuming that `isBaseThreadFinished.get()` and `...set()` methods don't do any sneaky tricks.) I'm betting that the problem here is a misunderstanding of how wait/notify works.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I actually got a AmazonSDKClientException before I could call notifyAll. @Thomas, S3 should be able to handle async HTTP calls. If I run into more problems, I'll have more info, but outside this function nothing interesting happens (small program)

Comment: @jameslarge I agree. However, since the code posted is so little I wasn't sure those are all instances of synchronization. Additionally the OP stated the main thread succeeded so if that one locked the monitor that would explain why all the others waited till it's finished.